# How to get the width of a Text component BEFORE it is rendered

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a text slider that moves from right to left over certain period of time. A problem is that I need it to come from outside the display and appear as it moves slowly to the left side. So I cannot use `onLayout` event as it would briefly appear in the display before it is animated.

How do I calculate the width of text component before it is rendered on the screen in react native?

Answer (score 0):

may be try `UIManager.measure`?
https://gist.github.com/johanneslumpe/e48acd0a820bb322790b